# What does the phrase AS YOU WERE mean?

Tags: quotes

A UK artist, Liam Gallagher, usually uses this phrase, but I can't understand what it really means.

Example taken from Twitter:

> That’s wiped me out of for a kip as you were LG x

Please could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: It's a military expression.  Google it.

Comment: I don't know what the tweet means, but see https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/what-does-as-you-were-mean

Comment: **As you were** = *In the manner/style that you previously had.* As a command = resume your previous position with the implication of the previous position was relaxed/informal or occupied with something else.

Comment: I’d guess he’s using *”as you were”* to mean *”if you will”* which is essentially asking the listener to indulge him his use of “wiped me out for a kip”

Comment: @Jim: That doesn't sound right to me. I think you're conflating *as you were* (return to your previous state, possibly implying that whatever I just said should be ignored) and *as **it** were* (so to speak, if you will, if you like).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  it doesn’t sound right to me either. I was just trying to guess what he *might* have meant.   The only thing that parses for me is with stress on *you*,  as in:  I was wiped out just as you were. But there’s not enough context to tell.  It’s certainly *not* the military command.

Comment: @Jim: I don't see how you can be so sure it's *not* the "military" sense. Well, presumably it's not *As you were!* in the sense of *At ease, men!* but it's still essentially the same usage when it means *Go back to doing whatever you were before you had to pay attention to an officer* (except the way *I'm* thinking of it, that's *Go back to **thinking** whatever you thought before I said something that I now acknowledge was mistaken*).